# cocos2d-x v3.6 FlipY3D does not flip at Y center position

Tags: cocos2d-x

When I tryo to FlipY3D the layer of the default hello world template, the conent will flip but also move to upper corner.

So, it is not flipped at Y-Center position anymore. It worked with v2.2.6

Here is my code which I added to the end of the HelloWorldScene.init() method:

```
// add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

// position the sprite on the center of the screen
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

NodeGrid* lNodeGrid = NodeGrid::create();
this->addChild(lNodeGrid);

// add the sprite as a child to this layer
lNodeGrid->addChild(sprite, 0);

CCFlipY3D* mFlipScreenY3D = CCFlipY3D::create(1);
lNodeGrid->runAction(mFlipScreenY3D);
```

Can someone please check this and help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you re-checking anchor point. It should be Vec2(0.5, 0.5) or just Vec2::ANCHOR_MIDDLE.